# An early 90s TV series in which aliens set up embassies on Earth

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm looking for an early 90s TV series in which aliens set up embassies on Earth.
They were human-like, with a pale blue skin.

Their ships were alive and grown rather than built.

The story focused on their ambassador in the US and its relationship with a human (cop?) who discovered little by little they were not the benefactors they appeared to be.

Oh, and they used nice smartphones with retractable screens.

Well, I can't tell much more about it...

Comment: looks like "final conflict " http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth:_Final_Conflict but they are not blue

Answer (score 15):

While I admit to not having watched the series, this description immediately made me think of [Earth: Final Conflict](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth:_Final_Conflict).

The primary aliens are the Taelons:

[image: Taelon]

They're pale, but don't look blue to me.  However, also in the Google Images search, numerous images of glowing blue humanoids came up:

[image: Taelon?]

The EFC Wikia [describes their ships as "biomechanoid"](http://efc.wikia.com/wiki/Taelon_Mothership), so while I haven't seen the series and don't know for sure if they're grown, it certainly sounds like they are:

[image: Taelon mothership]

The series ran from 1997 through 2002.

Comment: I'm trying not to dig in too far, since I do want to watch the series at some point!

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is the show I was looking for. I had this impression that the Taelons where blue-skinned, but they're not, maybe their environement of choice was blue-tinged as we can see on the first pic you posted.

Comment: @AlbertMancko- I remember this- the aliens' bodies were mostly energy (but not all), the ones who had 'skin' absorbed some DNA from touching humans & used it to look less spooky & threatening (that's how one described it in an episode called Defector).

Answer (score 4):

Sounds a lot like [Earth: Final Conflict](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%3a_Final_Conflict) to me.

The Aliens were kind of blue, they couldn't reproduce anymore and there was a cop/bodyguard type of guy who worked with the resistance if I remember correctly. I'm pretty sure this is what you're looking for.