# Old sci fi show where characters used a smart phone type device called a "global"

Tags: story-identification

What is the name of the series in which the characters used a smart phone type device called a "global?"  It was a cylinder out of which sprung a flexible screen so that it became a videophone.  In the last episode our heroes left Earth for an alien planet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An early 90s TV series in which aliens set up embassies on Earth](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/an-early-90s-tv-series-in-which-aliens-set-up-embassies-on-earth)

Comment: @N_Soong - We don't close story identification questions as duplicates unless both have accepted answers.

Comment: @WadCheber there's another few questions about the same thing and at least one I'm pretty sure has an accepted answer but I just couldn't find it!

Comment: I wouldn't call 90s 'old' by the way

Comment: @N_Soong I'm just saving Richard from having to say it.  :)

Comment: It's definitely Earth Final Conflict.

Answer (score 7):

Characters used devices called the [Global](http://earthfinalconflict.wikia.com/wiki/Global) in [Earth: Final Conflict](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0123816/).

[image]

Comment: Makes me really appreciate my iPhone lol